# Question regading the limit for a improper function

Tags: integration, limits

I simple do not understand why the value of the limit for the function with limits [b,-b] does not also diverge as with the first one. If you plug in "infinity" in the last function  the same thing should happend again as in the first function with +/-OO limits. Here is the question and the solution:
[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all, $~\infty~$ is **not** a number, but is instead merely a **symbol** of unbounded growth.  So, you can never (validly) *plug in* $~\infty.~$  Second of all, the problem is (in effect) distinguishing between $$\left\{ ~\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_0^b f(x) ~dx ~\right\} + \left\{ ~\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{-b}^0 f(x) ~dx ~\right\}$$ and $$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{-b}^b f(x) ~dx.$$

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is a bounded odd function in that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $-\frac12 \le f(x) \le \frac12$.  So clearly $\int_{-b}^0 f(x)\, dx = -\int_{0}^b f(x)\, dx $  and so   $\int_{-b}^b f(x)\, dx =0$ for all real $b$, and $\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} 0 = 0$

Comment: But just to spell out in plain english (for my sake). When you find the integral of the above function, which is1/2*ln(1+x^2), and then have evaluate it at +/- infinity or b/-b, were b goes towards infinity, i.e F(b)-F(a), then why dosent it end up with the same result. After all in the last example it also says that b→∞, so what difference does it make whether it is written lim_b→∞ for [b,-b] or having -/+∞ just written as the limits, it just make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

This exercise aims to show that although $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx$ diverges, this does not imply that the [Cauchy Principle Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) $PV(f)=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R f(x)\, dx$ diverges. Note that the function $z/(1+z^2)$ is undefined at $z=\pm i$ which isn't considered in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx$. However, through contour integration, it is possible to ensure that $PV(f)$ converges by integrating over a contour which avoids the singularity.

Comment: I have edited my response. Thanks!

Comment: But just to spell out in plain english (for my sake). When you find the integral of the above function, which is1/2*ln(1+x^2), and then have evaluate it - i.e F(b)-F(a) - at +/- infinity or [b,-b], were b goes towards infinity, then why dosent it end up with the same result. After all, in the last example it also says that b→∞, so what difference does it make whether it is written lim_b→∞ for [b,-b] or having -/+∞ just written as the limits, it just makes no sense to me.